# create a new column based on the other column

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, conditional-statements

New edited:
Can somebody please help me with the for loop?

The data looks like below: with the following index and one column with df['hold meaning'] with some string and some NaN value.

```
Index(['Creation Date', 'Booked Date', 'amount', 'Hold Date',
   'Hold Release Date', 'Hold Meaning', 'test'],
  dtype='object')

df['Hold Meaning']
0     Pricing
1    CS issue
2         NaN
3         NaN
4         NaN
```

---

original post
I am a newbie to python. I am stuck on this issue forever now:

What I want to do is to create a new column based on a condition of another column:

1) If the value in that column is NaN, I want the corresponding value in the new created column to be " clean "

2) If the value ( lower case ) contains certain string, I want the value to be 'x'

3) If the value does not contain certain string and not empty, I want it to be 'y'

I tried two different ways to do it:

1) Use np.where or (lambda expression), but it does not let me do lower.()

```
df1['test']=np.where(pd.isna(df1['Hold Meaning']),"clean",np.where(df1['Hold Meaning'].lower().str.contains('Pricing'),"cs",'not cs'))
```

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'

If i remove lower(), then it works, but that is not what i want.

2) I tried using a for loop and a "in"

```
for i in df1['Hold Meaning']:
  if pd.isna(i):
    df1['test1']='clean'
else:
  if 'pricing' in i.lower():
    df1['test1']='cs'
  else:
    df1['test1']='non cs'
```

the result is odd. everything in the new column becomes"clean". it seems it all goes to the first if:pd.isna(i) and returns truth, even not all the value is NaN.

Can somebody give me some tips on this? Thanks soo much.

Comment: As for the error, it's pd.Series. **str** .lower, in the same way you need `.str` before `.contains`

Comment: df1['test1']=np.where(df1['Hold Meaning'].str.lower().contains('Pricing'),'cs','non cs'), i tried this, but it gives me the error 'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: provide data sample

Comment: you need to add it for each operation, so it would be `.str.lower().str.contains()`. The result of `.str.lower()` is a `pd.Series`, so you again need to apply `.str.contains()` on that Series. You are just chaining together operations.

Comment: this is it! You are awesome @ALollz

Comment: Creation Date Booked Date amount Hold Date Hold Release Date Hold Meaning
2018-04-30 2017-10-10 -845.00 2018-04-30 18:17:06 2018-05-01 18:28:10 Pricing
2018-04-30 2017-10-10 -845.00 2018-05-17 01:22:40 2018-05-21 14:01:01 CS issue
2018-05-21 2017-10-10 500.00   
2018-05-25 2017-10-10 345.00   
2018-05-30 2017-09-25 525,254.00

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar i want to provide the sample, but the format is so messed up. any idea how can i do it right?